# Propositional logic. I would like to see a deduction of $\neg p$ from $p\to\bot$ according to the system described in the body of this question.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I found a nice script about mathematical logic [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Evddries/main2.pdf) (its author is
Lou van Dries).

Propositions are introduced as words on the alphabet $A\cup\left\{ \top,\bot,\neg,\vee,\wedge\right\} $
(where $A$ is a non-empty set) obtained by applying well known rules
(you can find them on page 14).

Every valuation on the propositions sends $\top$ to $1$ and sends $\bot$ to $0$.

The symbol $\to$ is formally not a part of the language but the expression
$p\to q$ serves as abbreviation of $\neg p\vee q$.

Propositional axioms introduced on the pages 19,20 and are formulas
of shape:

1. $\top$
2. $p\to\left(p\vee q\right)$ and $p\to\left(q\vee p\right)$
3. $\neg p\to\left(\neg q\to\neg\left(p\vee q\right)\right)$
4. $\left(p\wedge q\right)\to p$ and $\left(p\wedge q\right)\to q$
5. $p\to\left(q\to\left(p\wedge q\right)\right)$
6. $\left(p\to\left(q\to r\right)\right)\to\left(\left(p\to q\right)\to\left(p\to r\right)\right)$
7. $p\to\left(\neg p\to\bot\right)$
8. $\left(\neg p\to\bot\right)\to p$

Using Modus Ponens as inference rule this provides a deduction
system and on a neat way it is proven in the script that this system
is complete: if $\Sigma\vDash p$ then also $\Sigma\vdash p$ for any set $\Sigma$ of propositions.

Of course we have $\left\{ p\to\bot\right\} \vDash\neg p$ so we must
have $\left\{ p\to\bot\right\} \vdash\neg p$ as well, and my problem
is that I just cannot find a deduction of $\neg p$ from $\left\{ p\to\bot\right\} $. I really tried hard but with no essential result and hope sincerely that I overlooked something.

So my question is:

> Could someone provide me such a deduction of $\neg p$ from $p\to\bot$?

Actually it is the same thing as a deduction of $\neg p$ from $\neg p\vee\bot$ so that a deduction of $p$ from $p\vee\bot$ will also do.

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Beware -- you used "interference rule" not "inference rule". They are two completely different things. FTFY.

Comment: @PrimeMover Thank you for correcting!

Comment: I'm skimming too quickly, no doubt, but which theorem actually proves completeness? Can one prove $\neg\bot$??

Comment: @PeterSmith The order's a bit strange, but I believe the proof of Theorem 2.2.5 goes from Lemma 2.2.7 to the paragraph after Lemma 2.2.12. And the proof of Corollary 2.2.10 makes use of Theorem 2.2.5 to actually prove Theorem 2.2.3.

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes we can prove $\neg\bot$ now. In the answer of Alex it has been shown that $\neg p$ can be deduced from $p\to\bot$. Substituting $\bot$ for $p$ we find that $\neg\bot$ can be deduced from $\bot\to\bot$ and in the linked script it is proved that $p\to p$ can be deduced for every $p$ (so also $p=\bot$) in lemma 2.2.1..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that $\{p\to\bot,\lnot\lnot p,\lnot p\}$ is inconsistent. Indeed, $\lnot p\to (\lnot\lnot p\to \bot)$ is an instance of (7), and two applications of MP gives $\bot$.

By Corollary 2.2.8, $\{p\to \bot,\lnot \lnot p\}\vdash p$.

By MP, $\{p\to \bot,\lnot\lnot p\}\vdash \bot$, so $\{p\to \bot,\lnot\lnot p\}$ is inconsistent.

By Corollary 2.2.8 again, $\{p\to \bot\}\vdash \lnot p$.

---

Of course, this is a meta proof. You can extract a formal proof by unwinding the applications of Corollary 2.2.8, the proof of which uses the Deduction Lemma. If you go through this process, I expect you'll get a proof that's somewhere in the neighborhood of 40 lines. It's not clear to me whether a significantly shorter proof is possible in this system.

Comment: Thank you, Alex! The meta proof on its own is already enough. Things are clear now.

Comment: @drhab - formal derivation, reframing Alex's meta-proof: 1) $p→⊥$ - premise, 2) $¬¬p$ - premise 3) $¬p$ - premise, 4) $\vdash ¬p→(¬¬p→⊥)$ - Ax.7, 5)  $(¬¬p→⊥)$ - from 3) and 4) by MP; 6) $\bot$ - from 2) and 5) by MP, 7) $¬p→⊥$ - from premise 3) and 6) by **Lemma 3.1.3** (Deduction Lemma), 8) $\vdash (¬p→⊥)→p$ - Ax.8, 9) $p$ - from 7) and 8) by MP, 10) $\bot$ - from 1) and 9) by MP, 11) $(¬¬p→⊥)$ - from premise 2) and 10) by **Lemma 3.1.3** (Deduction Lemma), 12) $\vdash (¬¬p→⊥)→¬p$ - Ax.8, 13) $¬p$ - from 11) and 12) by MP.

Comment: Having discharged premises 2) and 3) using Deduction Lemma, the derivation amounts to: $p→\bot \vdash ¬p$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It was clear to me that the answer of Alex was sufficient, but you gave me an extra present with this nice deduction. Thank you, Mauro! Also the concept of "discharging premises" on base of deduction theorem (or RAA) is enlightening for me. A nice way to make deductions shorter.

Comment: @drhab - you are welcome :-)

Comment: One question how can the deduction theorem be true? I can’t see how to derive $a\to(b\to a)$.If that holds then it’s obviously true.

Comment: I can’t see that listed as an axiom

Comment: @VoiletFlame the author defines $p\to q$ to be shorthand for $\lnot p\lor q$. As an instance of axiom schema (2), we have $a\to (\lnot b\lor a)$, which is equal to $a\to(b\to a)$.

Comment: Oops, that’s what I get for not reading properly, thanks.